# How do I simply programmatically place a UIButton upon a host view via Constraints?

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, constraints

I want to programmatically generate an overview (UIButton) in the lower left-hand corner.

[image]
This is currently being done using Interface Builder.  However I need to repeat this for multiple host UIViews.  So I decided to write a utility class method to do this.

```
+ (UIButton *)attachGreenPlusButtonTo:(UIView *)hostView {

    NSLog(@"--- {attachGreenPlusButtonTo} ---");

    // Green Button --------------------------------------------------------------------
    UIImage *greenPlusImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_plus"];
    UIButton *greenButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [greenButton setImage:greenPlusImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    greenButton.tag = 22;

    [greenButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    [hostView addSubview:greenButton];

   //  Positioning the Green '+' Button:

        // Button is 4 pts from superview right edge:
        NSArray *horizontalConstraints =
        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[greenButton(==57)]-4-[hostView]"
                                                options:0
                                                metrics:nil
                                                  views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(hostView,greenButton)];

        [hostView addConstraints:horizontalConstraints];

        NSArray *verticalConstraints =
        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"V:[greenButton(==57)]-34-[hostView]"
                                                options:0
                                                metrics:nil
                                                  views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(hostView,greenButton)];

        [hostView addConstraints:verticalConstraints];

    [hostView layoutIfNeeded];

    return greenButton;
}
```

I'm getting close, but now the button is being positioned at (-61, -91).

What gives?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Call this after creating the `greenButton`:

```
[greenButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

otherwise the system will create (unwanted) constraints for you.

Your visual layout doesn't look right either.  Use *vertical bar* `|` to refer to the superview:

```
"H:[greenButton(==57)]-4-|"
```

and

```
"V:[greenButton]-34-|"
```

Comment: I've did that... got a UIButton value (without errors), but it's x/y coordinate is off:  
UIButton: 0x7f9775a83260; frame = (-61 -91; 57 57); -- via debugger.

... Getting closer!

Comment: I had tried that and got a bug; but found that the bug was apparently due to something else.   So I return to what you're saying.   It worked.   All appears to be okay.

Comment: Remove `hostView` from your dictionary when you use `|`.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had a problem using '|' for superview within the method due to a bug which eventually appeared to be due do something else.   So...

Upon feedback, I return to the use of '|' as the superview vs the 'hostView':

```
//  Positioning the Green '+' Button:
    // Button is 4 pts from superview right edge:
    NSArray *horizontalConstraints =
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[greenButton(==57)]-4-|"
                                            options:0
                                            metrics:nil
                                              views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(hostView,greenButton)];

    [hostView addConstraints:horizontalConstraints];

    NSArray *verticalConstraints =
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"V:[greenButton(==57)]-34-|"
                                            options:0
                                            metrics:nil
                                              views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(hostView,greenButton)];

    [hostView addConstraints:verticalConstraints];

    [hostView layoutIfNeeded];
```

This worked.
All appears to be okay now.